# django app deployment without subdomain

Tags: server, system-installation, apache2, django, uwsgi

I have deployed a django app to the server i have. Let say its ip is `192.168.1.1`. So i was able to access the any site there with `192.168.1.1/my_site`.

I have now deployed the `Django` App which is a small api. I am following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-16-04) tutorial and using the apache with mod_wsgi and with the daemon. now the problem when i deployed locally i was able to access it through the `localhost` but all the other sites were not accessible due to change in the `000-default-000.conf` file.

As i am deploying at the server is it possible to access through the ip and will not conflict with the other projects in `/var/www/html`?

Comment: Not done work with python but I know apache works with `VirtualHost` files, so perhaps you need to create one for that app!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen the files in `sites-available`?

Comment: Then create a virtualhost file for that app, there should no conflict!

Comment: but how will i access that with the wsgi?? like for the php files it automatically renders the index.php but for the python it should be configure in the virtual host. I can simply drop my app in the `/var/www/html` folder and access it like `192.168.1.1/my_site`

Answer (score 0):

Not a `Django + Apache` expert but found this off the web, see if it works for you.

From [django project](https://django-project-skeleton.readthedocs.io/en/latest/apache2_vhost.html)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # This is name based virtual hosting. So place an appropriate server name
    #   here. Example: django.devsrv.local
    ServerName  [[SERVER_NAME]]
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    # This alias makes serving static files possible.
    #   Please note, that this is geared to our settings/common.py
    #   In production environment, you will propably adjust this!
    Alias /static/  {{ project_directory }}/run/static/

    # This alias makes serving media files possible.
    #   Please note, that this is geared to our settings/common.py
    #   In production environment, you will propably adjust this!
    Alias /media/  {{ project_directory }}/run/media/

    # Insert the full path to the wsgi.py-file here
    WSGIScriptAlias /   {{ project_directory }}/{{ project_name }}/wsgi.py

    # PROCESS_NAME specifies a distinct name of this process
    #   see: https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIDaemonProcess
    # PATH/TO/PROJECT_ROOT is the full path to your project's root directory, 
    #   containing your project files
    # PATH/TO/VIRTUALENV/ROOT: If you are using a virtualenv specify the full
    #   path to its directory.
    #   Generally you must specify the path to Python's site-packages.
    WSGIDaemonProcess   {{ project_name }}  python-path={{ project_directory }}:{{ project_directory }}/../lib/python2.7/site-packages

    # PROCESS_GROUP specifies a distinct name for the process group
    #   see: https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIProcessGroup
    WSGIProcessGroup    {{ project_name }}

    # Serving static files from this directory
    #   Please note, that this is geared to our settings/common.py
    #   In production environment, you will propably adjust this!
    <Directory {{ project_directory }}/run/static>
        Options -Indexes
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    # Serving media files from this directory
    #   Please note, that this is geared to our settings/common.py
    #   In production environment, you will propably adjust this!
    <Directory {{ project_directory }}/run/media>
        Options -Indexes
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    LogLevel warn

    # PROJECT_NAME is used to seperate the log files of this application
    ErrorLog    ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/{{ project_name }}_error.log
    CustomLog   ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/{{ project_name }}_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

From [Metal Toad](https://www.metaltoad.com/blog/hosting-django-sites-apache)

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
 ServerName mysite.example.com 
 DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/mysite 
 WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/vhosts/mysite/myproject/wsgi.py 

 # adjust the following line to match your Python path 
 WSGIDaemonProcess mysite.example.com processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP} python-home=/var/www/vhosts/mysite/venv/lib/python3.5 
 WSGIProcessGroup mysite.example.com 

 <directory /var/www/vhosts/mysite> 
   AllowOverride all 
   Require all granted 
   Options FollowSymlinks 
 </directory> 

 Alias /static/ /var/www/vhosts/mysite/static/ 

 <Directory /var/www/vhosts/mysite/static> 
  Require all granted 
 </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

Metal Toad goes further to show you how to tweak your `wsgi.py` to get it to work well with `apache`:

```
"""
exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``. 
For more information on this file, see 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/wsgi/ 
""" 
import os 
import time 
import traceback 
import signal 
import sys 

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application 

sys.path.append('/var/www/vhosts/mysite') 
# adjust the Python version in the line below as needed 
sys.path.append('/var/www/vhosts/mysite/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages') 

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.settings") 

try: 
    application = get_wsgi_application() 
except Exception: 
    # Error loading applications 
    if 'mod_wsgi' in sys.modules: 
        traceback.print_exc() 
        os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGINT) 
        time.sleep(2.5)
```

So play around with it and get it to serve you. And Metal Toad says you can even setup several sites:

> The second Virtual Host is set up very similarly to the first. The main differences are the server names, paths, and the location of the wsgi.py file.

Comment: let me test this